# iOS Dynamic Link Builder explanation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to figure out how to use [Firebase's Dynamic Links for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create) to send custom deeplinks to people from my iOS application. However, the documentation doesn't have any comments and I'm a bit confused as to what the long piece of code given under **Create a long link from parameters** does. There's about 30 lines in a row without a single comment.

```
guard let linkString = dictionary[.link]?.text else { return }
guard let link = URL(string: linkString) else { return }
guard let domain = dictionary[.domain]?.text else { return }
let components = FIRDynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: domain)

let analyticsParams = FIRDynamicLinkGoogleAnalyticsParameters(
    source: dictionary[.source]?.text ?? "", medium: dictionary[.medium]?.text ?? "",
    campaign: dictionary[.campaign]?.text ?? "")
analyticsParams.term = dictionary[.term]?.text
analyticsParams.content = dictionary[.content]?.text
components.analyticsParameters = analyticsParams

if let bundleID = dictionary[.bundleID]?.text {
  let iOSParams = FIRDynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: bundleID)
  if let fallbackURL = dictionary[.fallbackURL]?.text {
    iOSParams.fallbackURL = URL(string: fallbackURL)
  }
  iOSParams.minimumAppVersion = dictionary[.minimumAppVersion]?.text
  iOSParams.customScheme = dictionary[.customScheme]?.text
  iOSParams.iPadBundleID = dictionary[.iPadBundleID]?.text
  if let iPadFallbackURL = dictionary[.iPadFallbackURL]?.text {
    iOSParams.iPadFallbackURL = URL(string: iPadFallbackURL)
  }
  iOSParams.appStoreID = dictionary[.appStoreID]?.text
  components.iOSParameters = iOSParams

  let appStoreParams = FIRDynamicLinkItunesConnectAnalyticsParameters()
  appStoreParams.affiliateToken = dictionary[.affiliateToken]?.text
  appStoreParams.campaignToken = dictionary[.campaignToken]?.text
  appStoreParams.providerToken = dictionary[.providerToken]?.text
  components.iTunesConnectParameters = appStoreParams
}

if let packageName = dictionary[.packageName]?.text {
  let androidParams = FIRDynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: packageName)
  if let androidFallbackURL = dictionary[.androidFallbackURL]?.text {
    androidParams.fallbackURL = URL(string: androidFallbackURL)
  }
  if let minimumVersion = dictionary[.minimumVersion]?.text, let intVersion = Int(minimumVersion) {
    androidParams.minimumVersion = intVersion
  }
  components.androidParameters = androidParams
}

let socialParams = FIRDynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
socialParams.title = dictionary[.title]?.text
socialParams.descriptionText = dictionary[.descriptionText]?.text
if let imageURL = dictionary[.imageURL]?.text {
  socialParams.imageURL = URL(string: imageURL)
}
components.socialMetaTagParameters = socialParams

longLink = components.url
print(longLink?.absoluteString ?? "")
```

Where exactly this `dictionary` at the top is coming from and what do the other parts accomplish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Firebase Dynamic Links documentation is really awful. I understood how it works by diving into the Firebase public API.

P.S [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/dynamiclinks/DynamicLinksExampleSwift/ViewController.swift) is the whole starter project where this snippet is cut from.

### Explanation of the important fields

- The **link** is a URL object containing the link you want to pass through with the parameters. [Watch](https://youtu.be/sFPo296OQqk?t=6m52s) for more information.
- The **domain** is a string containing your dynamic linking domain that can be found in the firebase console. (It's the link with *app*.goo.gl)
- **bundleID** is your application's bundle id. It can be found in your Xcode project.
- **fallback urls** are set only if you want a custom URL to be opened when the app is not installed instead of the app store page.
- **minimum app version** From the API documentation:

  > The the minimum version of your app that can open the link. If the installed app is an older version, the user is taken to the AppStore to upgrade the app. Note: It is app's developer responsibility to open AppStore when received link declares higher minimunAppVersion than currently installed.
- **custom scheme** Quoting the API documentation again:

  > The target app's custom URL scheme, if defined to be something other than the app's bundle ID.
- **iPad bundle id and iPad fallback URL** are set if you have a different application for the iPad.
- All of the **appStoreParams** should be found in your itunes connect page.
- Set the **androidParams** if you also have an Android app.

#### Also, this part was very vague in the documentation:

```
FIROptions.default().deepLinkURLScheme
```

This field should be set to the scheme you set in the Xcode project in the Info section under URL Types.

Comment: Not to be dense, but on the minimum app version, "If the installed app is an older version, the user is taken to the AppStore to upgrade the app."  And yet...it's the dev's responsibility to open the AppStore?  So this param basically does nothing unless you make it do something?